# How would I obtain the minimum gap between List elements?

Tags: scala

For example suppose I have a sorted list

val sorted = List(1, 5, 15, 37, 39, 42, 50)

The smallest gap is (39-37)=2. How would I obtain this result? I have been looking at foldLeft I get the feeling it is similar to what I need but not quite the right thing

Comment: If its a sorted list you can do what Matt Fenwick suggested in one iteration. it will cost O(N) Time. minGap = minGap < arr(i+1) - arr(i) ? minGap : arr(i+1) - arr(i); and check that the loop reaches N-1 so you wont go out of bounds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
val sorted = List(1, 5, 15, 37, 39, 42, 50)
(sorted.tail,sorted).zipped.map(_-_).min
//res2: Int = 2
```

**[Edit]**

You can use a fold as well:

```
sorted.tail.foldLeft((sorted.head,Int.MaxValue))((x,y) => (y, math.min(y-x._1,x._2)))._2
```

Answer (score 12):

```
val sorted = List(1, 5, 15, 37, 39, 42, 50)

sorted match { 
  case Nil => None
  case List(a) => None
  case l => Some(l.sliding(2).map{case Seq(a, b) => math.abs(a - b)}.min)
}
// res1: Option[Int] = Some(2)
```

`sliding` returns an iterator, so that should only traverse the list once.

If you are interested to find which two elements have the smallest gap, you can also use minBy. So here is another variation, just for fun.

```
sorted.view.zip(sorted.tail).minBy(t => math.abs(t._1 - t._2))
// res4: (Int, Int) = (37,39)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I would do:

1. write a function that transforms a list of n numbers into a list of (n - 1) gaps
2. write/use a function that selects the smallest number from a list

Don't forget to handle the empty list case for part 1!  (Incidentally, Part 2 could be written as a fold).

Comment: Can (1) be done without a for loop? I was trying to use a functional solution

Comment: @deltanovember -- of course!  There's lots of purely functional ways to do 1.  One way would use recursion!

Answer (score 1):

Using foldLeft:

```
   sorted match {    
      case Nil | List(_) => None
      case x :: xs => Some(
        (xs.foldLeft((Integer.MAX_VALUE, x)) {
          case ((min, prev), next) => (math.min(min, next - prev), next)
        })._1
      )
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Imperative (and possible faster) version:

```
  if (sorted.isEmpty) {
    None
  } else {
    var sortedTail = sorted.tail
    if (sortedTail.isEmpty) {
      None
    } else {
      var minDiff = Int.MaxValue
      var prev = sorted.head
      do {
        val curr = sortedTail.head
        minDiff = minDiff min math.abs(curr - prev)
        sortedTail = sortedTail.tail
        prev = curr
      } while (!sortedTail.isEmpty)
      Some(minDiff)
    }
  }
```